# List initialization and copy elision

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, copy-elision, list-initialization

Consider the following example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
struct A
{
    A(int, char*){};
    A(const A&){ printf("copy-ctor\n"); }
};
int main()
{
    A x = A(5, nullptr);
}
```

According to 8.5.16 (of C++11 standard) the line

```
    A x = A(5, nullptr);
```

is treated as

```
    A x(A(5, nullptr));
```

(i.e. a temporary object of type A is created and passed to copy-ctor of type A to initialize an x). Then according to 12.8.31 compiler is allowed (**but is not forced**) to perform an optimization called "copy elision" to eliminate the creation of a temporary of type A which effectively makes that line of code to become

```
    A x(5, nullptr);
```

(i.e. no temporaries created, no copy-ctors called).

Now, suppose I use a list-initialization in the example above like this:

```
    A x = {5, nullptr}; // (1)
```

or

```
    A x = A{5, nullptr}; // (2)
```

Can someone please **quote the appropriate pharagraphs from C++11 standard** that confirm or deny that (1) and/or (2) would **always** (i.e. not only when compiler can do "copy elision" optimization) be treated as

```
    A x(5, nullptr);
```

(i.e. first constructor of A is being directly called, no temporaries created, no copying of objects of type A is performed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This answer is apparently wrong, which surprised me to learn. See the comments. I think the first and fourth bullet points of [dcl.init.list]/3 are what mean (1) invokes a constructor (or performs aggregate init) directly, without a temporary.**

There is nothing in the standard that guarantees that (1) and (2) avoid a temporary. They are both copy-initialization, (1) is copy-list-initialization as defined by [dcl.init.list] p1:

> List-initialization can occur in direct-initialization or copy-initialization contexts; list-initialization in a direct-initialization context is called *direct-list-initialization* and list-initialization in a copy-initialization context is called *copy-list-initialization*.

In both cases it is copy-initialization, and [dcl.init] says that may involve a move (which can be elided).

`8.5/14,15`:

> The initialization that occurs in the form
>
> `T x = a;`
>
> [...] is called copy-initialization.
>
> The initialization that occurs in the forms
>
> `T x(a);`
>
> `T x{a};`
>
> [...] is called direct-initialization.

If your compiler is not smart enough to always elide the temporary, then to ensure no temporary with list-initialization you can use direct-list-initialization, i.e.

```
A x{5, nullptr};
```

Comment: @Jonathan Somehow I was under the impression that "uniform initialization" (among other things) was meant to do away with difference between direct and copy initialization (and was desperately tring to find a confirmation in the standard). Now that you confirmed it is not the case I will sleep with a clear conscience. :) Thanks!

Comment: Jonathan, this is not correct. `A x = {5, nullptr};` will not involve a move. Only `A x = A{5, nullptr};` will involve a move (which is elidable), of course, because he explicitly creates the temporary.